# how to get object numbers in django models

Tags: django, count, model

I am a new user in Django and I am trying to print the total number of objects in a model but this code below prints the query set with its title. Here's my function

def showthis(request):

```
count= Item.objects.count()
print (count)
```

I need to get the total number of objects in Model Item

Answer (score 0):

```
items = Item.objects.all()
print(items.count())
```